# Understanding the definition of Cauchy sequence

Tags: real-analysis

For all $\epsilon > 0$ we found $N=N(\epsilon) : |x_n−x_m|<\epsilon$ for all $n,m > N$ ..... How I can prove that $\{x_n=1/n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is a Cauchy sequence ?

Comment: Just straight up use the definition to show that $|1/n - 1/m|$ can get as small as you want when $n, m $ get really big

Comment: ... and in particular for all $m \gt n$ you have $\left| \dfrac1n - \dfrac1m\right| \lt \dfrac1n \to 0$ as $n$ increases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the difference of $x_n$ and $x_m$, i.e. $|x_n-x_m|$, we want to find $N$ such that the difference can be as small as possible for any $n,m>N$,

if $n=m$, then difference is zero.

if $n\neq m$, then $|x_n-x_m|$=$|\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{m}|=\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{m}<\frac{1}{n}$. As by the Archimedean Property, we can always find $N$ such that $1/n$ can be sufficiently small as $n>N$, so this ensures $|x_n-x_m|$ can be sufficiently small as $n>N$. Then $x_n$ is Cauchy.